# How to add an HDMI output to my PC?

Tags: video, graphics-card, hdmi, dvi, hdvideo

I'm moving, and am going to buy a new HDTV for the apartment. I'm thinking about connecting my self-built PC to the TV. The only thing is that my PC has only one PCIx16 2.0 slot. The card in that slot has two DVI ports. I have two monitors, and I would like to keep both of them connected by DVI. That leaves me with 0 available HD outputs.

I need to add another HD video output to my computer, preferably HDMI. I saw this card on Newegg called the BFG Tech BFGRGTX2951792H2OCLE. It has two DVI and one HDMI, so I could replace my current video card with it. However, this card costs $850. For that amount of money, I can just buy a separate HTPC.

How can I add an additional HDMI output to my desktop PC at a reasonable price?

Comment: Just realized something. I have this video card: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814130318 It has an "HDTV" output. Basically a component video cable. Will that support 1080p? Will it support HDCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into adding a PCI card with DVI or HDMI onto it to power the HDTV. Assuming you don't plan on gaming on it and just want to watch HD content, this should be more than enough and will keep you out of the extremely high-priced triple interface cards.

Edit: Suggestions

Anything from this list should be good. They all have DVI and are HDCP compliant, but adapters to HDMI are cheap.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2010380048+1069609642+1305520548+1320022195&QksAutoSuggestion=&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&Configurator=&Subcategory=48&description=&Ntk=&CFG=&SpeTabStoreType=&srchInDesc=

If you have an unused PCIe x1 slot then http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814161280 should work even better as it has a native HDMI port.

I'm sure if you shop around you can find better prices on all of these, they're just examples.

Comment: Can you suggest a specific card? I would prefer NVidia, so I wouldn't have to have two separate sets of video drivers.

Comment: Updated original post with examples.

Answer (score 0):

DVI and HDMI are basicly the same cable. (other than HDMI also has audio)

http://www.svideo.com/dvihdmi2.html

http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=hdmi+dvi+adapter

you could also try something like a USB converter... but they will probably have poor video performance.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=hdmi+usb

Comment: I know this already. I don't want to convert my DVI to HDMI. I'm already using both of my DVI. I want to ADD another one.

Comment: You could add another normal video card with DVI output and use a DVI to HDMI cable to output to your TV.

Answer (score 0):

There are [152](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2010380048+1320923120&QksAutoSuggestion=&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&Configurator=&Subcategory=48&description=&Ntk=&CFG=&SpeTabStoreType=&srchInDesc=) cards on Newegg that feature 1 HDMI output. Since you can add a card to your existing machine pick one that fits the interface types you do have open like PCIe X1 ([there's 1](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814161280)) AGP (there's 4) or just PCI (Newegg doesn't have one but they exist). Also consider getting a card that does not feature an HDMI output, but which has the interface type you can support and get an output converter to HDMI, maybe from [monoprice.com](http://monoprice.com/).